# Drop Table Based on Week or Month table was created

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a query that runs daily, and pushes data to the following tables:

- Daily Dashboard
- Weekly Dashboard
- Monthly Dashboard
- Yearly Dashboard

The daily file pushes data to the other 3 tables and is dropped daily. What I'm trying to figure out is how to put a trigger/command into the drop table command for the weekly and monthly tables.

- The Weekly File Needs to Drop every Monday

And

- The Monthly File needs to Drop on the 1st Day of each month

I'm assuming I'd need to have some sort of declaration like

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth as date SET @CurrentMonth = month(GetDate())
DECLARE @CurrentWeek as date SET @CurrentWeek = week(GetDate())
```

And then compare the current week/month against the date the table was created

eg:

```
IF CurrentWeek > CreatedWeek - Drop Table
IF CurrentMonth > CreatedMonth - Drop Table
```

Does anyone know if thats achievable, or if there is a better way of going about this?

Any help/advice is appreciated

Comment: Where do you call your `drop table command` from? Because a better solution would be to build a stored procedure to handle it all rather than messing around with triggers.

Comment: TBH  - i'm still learning, the Drop Table is inside the query, I know of stored procedures, but have never actually used one.

Comment: When you say "inside the query" what do you mean? And where are you calling it from? I suspect you mean a collection of statements/queries?

Comment: Better question is why? Why do you need to repeatedly drop and create the same tables? Or are you embedding a day/week/month/year value in the table names? If the latter, it is far easier to add your "period" key as a column - you can then store any number of daily/weekly/monthly/year values in the same tables. You can easily purge "old" rows whenever you want.

Comment: Not sure i follow, apologies - 

All of the code for the job im creating is sitting inside the one query, there are no external calls to other queries. The drop table commands are placed inline with the code that inserts data into each table ie

>Check if Drop_Table is required
>If No_Drop is required
>Insert Data From Daily_File

Comment: @SMor - The tables are being used in a PHP dashboard in a different location, Each table is called to a seperate tab ie Daily/Weekly etc - i did consider just deleting the rows from each table when required, but dropping seemed like a safer option as the Delete/Where clause may leave old rows in the table

Comment: "All of the code for the job im creating is sitting inside the one query" - thats not called a query, thats a collection of queries and statements. So you are running them from SQL Server Management Studio? In which case add your drop table logic there... and I'd encapsulate it within a stored procedure.

Comment: @DaleK - Correct, in MSSQL, ill take a better look at stored procedures, thanks

Comment: FYI Management Studio (SSMS) **is not** SQL Server - which is the database engine. SSMS is just a client interface to the engine (or multiple engines).

Comment: But back to your original question, write your logic as part of your existing code block and test it before you worry about creating a stored procedure.

Comment: How do you know what date the table was created?

Comment: @DaleK When creating the table, i insert Loaded_Date, Loaded_Month, Loaded_Week, Loaded_Year into columns

Comment: Why are you dropping and recreating the tables instead of just truncating them when you move the data from each table into the next one? You could do this simply in a stored procedure with two SQL statements. One stored proc per move (DailyToWeekly, WeeklyToMonthly, MonthlyToYearly) would do it, and scheduled jobs could call the job on the appropriate dates.

Comment: @KenWhite - Thanks, this looks interesting - ill take a look.